Failing to launch an instance in OpenStack (I just configured a self-service network)
PROBLEM: We deployed OpenStack in a cluster and until now we could launch instances using a provider (flat) network. Today we configured a self-service network to be able to use vxlan as well, although now we get an error when launching the instance with the new self-service network and the previous provider network. Here's the collection of errors I found in OpenStack logs and the Dashboard (Horizon):
ERRORS
Horizon
Error/Fault:

Message
Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance fe6fdc06-5ef8-4ace-8738-15a270dd2809.


Code 500


Details
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 705, in build_instances raise exception.MaxRetriesExceeded(reason=msg) nova.exception.MaxRetriesExceeded: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance fe6fdc06-5ef8-4ace-8738-15a270dd2809.

Neutron
Error 1 (neutron_dhcp_agent, in compute node):

ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent OSError: [Errno 38] failed to open netns

Error 2 (neutron-openvswitch-agent, in controller node):

2024-07-28 16:09:09.564 401936 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.utils [None req-08afcc05-b578-4440-8380-7478e8f295b1 - - - - - -] Exit code: 1; Cmd: ['iptables-save', '-t', 'raw']; Stdin: ; Stdout: ; Stderr: iptables-save v1.8.10 (legacy): Cannot initialize: Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

Warn 1 (ovs_vswitchd, in compute node):

2024-07-11T22:05:15.020Z|34365|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tapb6300b35-d0 (No such device)
2024-07-11T22:05:15.034Z|34366|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tapbd42e760-bc (No such device)

Nova
Error 1 (nova-compute):

2024-07-11 22:08:26.463 1339 ERROR nova.compute.manager nova.exception.InvalidDiskInfo: Disk info file is invalid: qemu-img failed to execute on /var/lib/nova/instances/0ae813eb-8d8d-4eac-aada-efa6e8d89597/disk : Unexpected error while running command.

More information that might be useful about neutron configuration:
[ml2]

type_drivers = flat,vlan,local,vxlan

tenant_network_types = vxlan,local

mechanism_drivers = openvswitch

